# Executing command line commands on a remote server

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-12.04, iptables

I have a server running HAProxy, and would like to change iptables on that server in order to preform some maintenance on my app servers.  What would be the easiest way to do this?  Is there a way I can preform system commands on a remote machine from C++? Or would I need to have a program running on the HAProxy machine in order to change the iptables for that machine? Any guidiance for this would be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason ssh doesn't work for you?  Surely you're already using that for remote access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh <hostname> "iptables <parameters>" from linux

plink <hostname> "iptables <parameters>" from Windows
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never used ssh as a single command, just as a shell, I guess I'll setup a key and use this method, it should work for what I am doing.

Comment: This is indeed what you want, but a simple warning - beware if `iptables <whatever>` does something that will break your `ssh` connection, or the ability to establish a new one.

Answer (score 0):

use libssh or as stated earlier execute commands with in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Give salt a try. It has remote command execution via agents via ssl. It works really well.

Saltstack.org